# Есть ли возможность для скомпилированного файла сделать врапер для управления программой?

Tags: node.js, binary-file

У меня есть скомпилированная программа

program
Она имеет свои методы.
getFile
last
и т. д.

Есть ли возможность запускать и управлять этим бинарным файлом не из консоли, а на Node.js запустить его и передавать ему комманды ?